# Evee lights are not showing/shining, beside the sun

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

[image: Screen shot of the light]I having some trouble in evee about the lights. My other project work fine but for some reason the light which includes the point,spot,area. I do not know if it was a setting I change or what. This is the version 2.83.20 of blender. (Sorry if this is a noob question, I am new to this software)

What I did: Turn high quality normals.

Comment: Hello maybe share your file or at least show a screenshot of your whole interface

Comment: I just edit the question the screen shot of the light not shining should be on there

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=y3gpa7kx" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/y3gpa7kx/)

Comment: I think that is it... sorry if the file in blender is messy lol

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're talking about, there are 2 suns and they seem to both work the way they should, could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you add a  point light or any other light beside the sun it does not shine?? The only light that works is the sun

Comment: It works with any other kind of lamp, it's just that 1) the strength needs to be much higher 2) your material is black 3) as you have overlapping vertical objects and they all have their own material, when you change their material you may not see the change right away

Comment: Thank you so much... sorry if it was a stupid question

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new light, make sure that its strength is high enough, 4 is ok for a *Sun* but not for a *Point*, increase it up to 4,000 (or more, depending on their proximity to the object).

As a side note, your vertical blocks are overlapping and have different materials, and you've disabled the *Scene World* option in the *Viewport Shading* panel.